# Setting caption on an imported minted file in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, captions, minted

I'm trying to add a caption to a code file referenced via `\inputminted` on a beamer frame. The listing part works as expected in my thesis (using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}`), but not inside my presentation.
The code is displayed correctly without the `listing` environment and the `caption`. If i use only `inputminted` with `caption`, I get

`LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`

If I try to use just the `listing` environment, I get

`! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

I'm using Overleaf with LuaLaTex. What is the correct way to achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    %\begin{listing}
        \inputminted[breaklines,linenos,fontsize=\small]{csharp}{MyCodeFile.cs}
    %    \caption{A caption}
    %\end{listing}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\begin{listing}[H]`... (note: the `[fragile]` option is not required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with `\begin{listing}[H]`... (the `[H]` is required as you can't use floating object with `beamer`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Test listing}
  
  \begin{listing}[H]
  \mint{cl}/(car (cons 1 '(2)))/
  \caption{Example of a listing.}
  \label{lst:example}
  \end{listing}
  Listing \ref{lst:example} contains an example of a listing.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `[H]` did it, thanks!